# SQL INSERT INTO SELECT query for updating on same table with some modification

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design

I want to update this table

```
Table name: Student

Name      Department

Alex         CSE
Bob          EEE
Briyan       ME
```

by copying all rows with some modification like this table:

```
Table name: Student

Name      Department

Alex         CSE
Bob          EEE
Briyan       ME
Mr. Alex     SCIENCE(CSE)
Mr. Bob      SCIENCE(EEE)
Mr. Briyan   SCIENCE(ME)
```

What should be the SQL query ... can you help please?

I have tried this far:

```
INSERT INTO 
    Student (Name, Department)
SELECT Name,Department FROM Student;
```

Answer (score 2):

So you're close you just need to add the data modifications you want to each field in your `SELECT` list like so:

```
INSERT INTO 
    Student (Name, Department)
SELECT CONCAT('Mr. ', Name), CONCAT('SCIENCE(', Department, ')') FROM Student;
```

You can use the [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to [concatenate strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5975980/5059085)

Answer (score 0):

I would *strongly* recommend that you **do not** do this.

You are attempting to store *multiple* bits of information into single fields and that is breaking one of the most *basic* tenets of Relational Database Design - atomicity.  Databases are really good at finding small bits of data and putting them together.  They're really *not* very good at finding big bits of information and tearing them apart.

"Mr. Alex" is *two* bits of information - the person's Title and their Forename.  These should be kept in *separate* fields.
Why?  Because each can change *independently* of the other and having them in separate fields makes that really easy to do.

"SCIENCE(CSE)" is also *two* bits of information - not sure what names you use to describe them, but I'm going to go with Faculty and Department.

Your table**s** ought to look more like this:

```
/* Assuming that a Student can only be part of *one* Department: */ 

select * from Student ; 

+-------+----------+-----------+
| title | forename | dept_code | 
+-------+----------+-----------+
| Mr.   | Alex     | CSE       |
| Mr.   | Bob      | EEE       |
| Mr.   | Briyan   | ME        |
+-------+----------+-----------+

/* You need data about each Department */

select * from Department ; 

+------+-------------+
| code | name        | ... 
+------+-------------+
| CSE  | Comp.Sci.   | ... 
| EEE  | Engineering | ... 
| ME   | Math        | ... 
+------+-------------+

/* You need to know which Faculty each Department belongs to */ 

select * from FacultyDepartment ; 

+----------+-----------+
| fac_code | dept_code | 
+----------+-----------+
| SCIENCE  | CSE       | 
| SCIENCE  | EEE       | 
| SCIENCE  | ME        | 
+----------+-----------+

/* You need data about each Faculty */ 

select * from Faculty ; 

+---------+---------+ 
| code    | name    | ... 
+---------+---------+ 
| SCIENCE | Science | ... 
+---------+---------+
```

So (finally) to construct your desired data:

```
select 
  s.title || ' ' || s.forename name 
, df.dept_code || '(' || df.faculty_code || ')' dept 
from Students s
inner join DepartmentFaculty df 
      on   s.dept_code = df.dept_code 
order by 1, 2 ; 

+------------+--------------+
| name       | department   |
+------------+--------------+
| Mr. Alex   | SCIENCE(CSE) | 
| Mr. Bob    | SCIENCE(EEE) | 
| Mr. Briyan | SCIENCE(ME)  | 
+------------+--------------+
```